# How to get container CPU/memory usage on Autopilot cluster in Prometheus

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, autopilot

How can I get container level metrics on a GKE Autopilot cluster in Prometheus?  IIUC, I need to use the node exporter, but that is prohibited on GKE Autopilot clusters.